# Extraer datos de Json desde PHP y obtener valores específicos del Json

Tags: php, json

Tengo la información Json de la siguiente forma en MySQL

```
{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/m67smI1IIMmYzCl9axvKNULVKLr.jpg","belongs_to_collection":{"id":10194,"name":"Toy Story Collection","poster_path":"/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg","backdrop_path":"/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg"},"budget":175000000,"genres":[{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"}]}}
```

Para Extraer backdrop_path utilizo el siguiente código y me muestra el resultado correcto "/m67smI1IIMmYzCl9axvKNULVKLr.jpg"

```
echo json_decode($datos_movies, true)["backdrop_path"];
```

Si lo hago con el mismo código con genres me da como resultado "Array"

```
echo json_decode($datos_movies, true)["genres"];
```

Ocupo de la ayuda para modificar el codigo y que me muestre la información completa (Adventure / Animation / Comedy / Family / Fantasy).

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿Solucionaron tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso puedes emplear `implode()` y `array_reduce()` de la siguiente forma:

```
echo implode('/',array_reduce(json_decode($datos_movies, true)["genres"], function ($carry, $item)
{
    $carry []= $item['name'];
    return $carry;
}));
```

Esto te retornará:

> Adventure/Animation/Comedy/Family/Fantasy

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciono

Answer (score 2):

La función [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) devuelve una matriz asociativa cuando indicamos el segundo parámetro en `true`. Teniendo esto en cuenta podrías aplicar la siguiente solución:

```
$movie = json_decode($datos_movies, true);
$genres = array_map(function($gen) { return $gen['name']; }, $movie['genres']);
echo implode(' / ', $genres);
```

**Salida:**

```
Adventure / Animation / Comedy / Family / Fantasy
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a84cab63280b5f1d621d45ba97c41a81e948132)</kbd>

**NOTA:** Por razones de rendimiento yo haría solo una vez el `json_decode($datos_movies, true)`

---

**Referencias:**

- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)
- [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)

Comment: interesante respuesta, +1 por espíritu deportivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono